# delphi/Lazarus/pascal , how to conver integer to byte array ？

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I use Lazarus , but less document , I want convert integer to byte array , Distinguish between big-endian and small-endian.

for example
i is 1
I want convert to byte array
00,00,00,01 and 01,00,00,00
big and small .

Comment: What are your attempts so far? Where did you succeed and where did you fail?

Comment: Why do you want to do this both big and little endian? If you are sending the integer over TCP/IP then you probably should leave these conversions to the standard networking functions host-to-network and network-to-host. And if that's the case then you don't actually need a byte array, because you can just interpret the integer as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for CPUs that are Little-Endian:

```
FUNCTION BigEndian(V : UInt32) : TBytes;
  VAR
    I : Int32;
   
  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,4);
    FOR I:=LOW(Result) TO HIGH(Result) DO BEGIN
      Result[I]:=(V AND $FF000000) SHR 24;
      V:=(V AND $00FFFFFF) SHL 8
    END
  END;

FUNCTION LittleEndian(V : UInt32) : TBytes;
  VAR
    I : Int32;
   
  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,4);
    FOR I:=LOW(Result) TO HIGH(Result) DO BEGIN
      Result[I]:=V AND $000000FF;
      V:=V SHR 8
    END
  END;
```

Another option for LittleEndian (again - on Little-Endian CPUs):

```
FUNCTION LittleEndian(V : UInt32) : TBytes;
  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,4);
    MOVE(V,Result[0],4)
  END;
```

Don't know enough about Lazarus to know if it compiles unmodified there, but the above compiles fine in Delphi.

Endian-agnostic versions:

```
FUNCTION BigEndian(V : UInt32) : TBytes;
  VAR
    I : Int32;

  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,4);
    FOR I:=HIGH(Result) DOWNTO LOW(Result) DO BEGIN
      Result[I]:=V MOD 256;
      V:=V DIV 256
    END
  END;

FUNCTION SmallEndian(V : UInt32) : TBytes;
  VAR
    I : Int32;

  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,4);
    FOR I:=LOW(Result) TO HIGH(Result) DO BEGIN
      Result[I]:=V MOD 256;
      V:=V DIV 256
    END
  END;
```

Comment: You could also add an example using ``absolute`` keyword.

Comment: @DelphiCoder So could you